# (WEBPACK) Add publicpPath to script and link in generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Hi guys i'm new to webpack. All my resource file are inside a specific folder so i gave a public path value say 
`module.exports = {
    publicPath:  '/karomi/web-viewer/dist/',

};`

and then after running `npm run build` script tag generated in my index.html inside the dist folder should be like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/karomi/web-viewer/dist/js/app.js"></script>
```

But instead i get

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong here? Why is the public path not appended to the resource paths?